# How to get last 10 rows from mysql table containing only text field

Tags: mysql

I am using table containing only text fields. How can I get last 10 rows from that table. There is no specific column for ordering.

I am trying like this but not working

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bhaskar_home_link` 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET n-10 
where n=(select count(*) from `bhaskar_home_link`)
```

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  If you don't have an auto-incremented id or timestamp, there is no definition of "last ten rows".

Comment: ...or some other way of ordering rows

Comment: How old is the table? Is there a lot of data? I only ask, because if it isn't too much of a headache, it might be worth adding an auto increment column.  Otherwise, try vidaica's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262082/how-to-get-last-10-rows-from-mysql-table-containing-only-text-field?answertab=active#tab-top), but will need some updating.